# What does a REGISTRATION; NEGATIVE; RESPONSE; UNICAST message mean (UDP 137)?

Tags: networking, server-message-block, netbios

I am seeing on the gateway of a WiFi network a flood of these messages:

```
12:32:53.334215 IP PRINTER.netbios-ns > 10.10.10.254.netbios-ns: NBT UDP PACKET(137): REGISTRATION; REQUEST; UNICAST
12:32:53.334295 IP 10.10.10.254.netbios-ns > PRINTER.netbios-ns: NBT UDP PACKET(137): REGISTRATION; NEGATIVE; RESPONSE; UNICAST
```

**What do they mean, exactly?** Where is the host trying to register? To which service?

*(Note: I previously asked a question about these messages in the context of the printer sending them but since there were no answers I would like to understand the underlying message to try to fix it myself)*

Comment: Next time, please edit the question instead. Also: Don't be too impatient. You asked the question on a sunday (our slowest day) and the majority of users (in the US) will only just start their day now.

Comment: @Sven: I realized in the meantime that my question was probably too specific, i.e. that it dealt with a specific device while the problem may have been a more general one (NetBIOS registration). I should have edited it instead, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution, without clearly understanding the reason.

A [post](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=769714) brought me to the right direction:

> The specific traffic you're seeing is SMB traffic as the machine
>   attempts to register itself with the master browser/force a browser
>   election.

My gateway server has `samba` enabled and looking at `nmdb` logs I realized that there was continously the message

```
[2016/03/21 12:57:18.985257,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_incomingrequests.c:213(process_name_registration_request)
  process_name_registration_request: unicast name registration request received for name PRINTER<20> from IP 10.10.10.20 on subnet UNICAST_SUBNET. Error - should be sent to WINS server
```

I edited `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to enable the WINS server (`wins support = yes` and `wins server = 10.10.10.254`) on this host (it was disabled by default) which ended the problem.

Comment: Just to add, avoid using both `wins support = yes` and `wins server = ...` in the same config file. Use the 1st when you want your samba to act like a wins server and use the 2nd if you want your samba to communicate to another wins server.